# jigsaw "requires transitive" not working

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, requires

Hi I currently have the problem that the "requires transitive" directive does not open the used module in my dependent module.

To get familiar with jigsaw I started to write a new application with spring and JDK 10. I got a module named "**database**" that uses **spring.data.jpa** module. Additionally I got a second module named "**mvc**" that requires the module "**database**".

Now in the module-info.java in module "**database**" I defined the spring module as follows:

```
requires transitive spring.data.jpa;
```

I would expect to have this module also available in my module "**mvc**" but I do not. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

module-info.java of module **database**

```
 module database {

    requires java.sql;
    requires java.persistence;
    requires liquibase.core;

    requires spring.beans;
    requires transitive spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.jdbc;
    requires spring.tx;
    requires spring.orm;

    exports de.database.entities to mvc;
    exports de.database.repositories to mvc;
  }
```

module-info.java of module **mvc**

```
module mvc {

    requires database;

    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot;

    exports de.mvc to application;

}
```

and as I said spring.data.jpa cannot be accessed in module **mvc**. Also the require directive **requires spring.data.jpa** is not possible.

**EDIT:**

database -> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    implementation group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb'
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence', name: 'hibernate-jpa-2.1-api'
    implementation(group: 'org.liquibase', name: 'liquibase-core')

    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api'

    testImplementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2')
}
```

mvc -> build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
    implementation (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter') {
        force = true
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

//    implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa'

    implementation project(":database")
}
```

The problem here is that if I leave the dependency **spring-data-jpa**  uncommented in module **mvc** the compilation will fail. I need to explicitly enable it in build.gradle eventhough it should be present as transitive dependency by the **database** module.

my error then is

```
> Task :mvc:compileJava FAILED
error: module not found: spring.data.jpa
1 error
```

I try to modularize the database part. The database part uses spring-repositories. So I use the interface **JpaRepository** that is in the module spring.data.jpa like this:

```
@Repository
public interface DestinationDao
  extends JpaRepository<Destination, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Destination>
{

}
```

And now I want to use this bean in my module **mvc**. This should work in my opinion even if I do not define the dependency on spring-data-jpa explicitly in the module **mvc**.

Comment: Could you share the code involved in the problem and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the following:
module database has a dependency via gradle.build to spring-data-jpa. This module should now expose this library to module mvc.

providing the sourcecode would be a little bit more of work. Even if it is just a test program it has become quiet big

Comment: Couldn't really figure out the line drawn between `opens` and `requires transitive` for your use case. Maybe the code could help.

Comment: "spring.data.jpa cannot be accessed in module mvc."  --- I think you need to explain this a bit more. Can you paste in the compile time or run time error that you are seeing?

Comment: @Goldfish Please run Gradle for the _mvc_ module with `--debug` and look for a debug message "Compiler arguments:" - is the Spring Data JPA JAR on the module path? (I would guess not.)

Answer (score 0):

Your module declarations are correct and *mvc* should read *spring.data.jpa*.

I guess you're getting a compile error? I'm not a Gradle expert, so I might be wrong here, but I think Gradle has a mode where it only uses direct dependencies during compilation. If *spring.data.jpa* were not in *mvc*'s dependency list (in Gradle), then that would explain the problem.

To figure that out, run Gradle with `--debug` and look for a debug message "Compiler arguments:".

If that's not the case, please share exactly when and what error you get.

Comment: As you already suspected I am getting a compile error. But only if I run the application with gradle. If I start it in IntelliJ as springboot configuration everything is fine. With my gradle startscript on the other hand I am getting '> Task :mvc:compileJava FAILED
error: module not found: spring.data.jpa'

Comment: I'm pretty sure the dependency is not on the module path. I edited the answer with a tip how to find out.

Comment: I edited the question with some additional information. Hope this clarifies my problem.